How to mount/see files/use files from usb in docker container?
What I want to do is to use files mounted from USB to container. I have windows host and I am using such configuration in docker-compose.yml -
backend:
    volumes:
      - "G:/preseed:/superCoolCatalog"

G: is usb stick on windows. When this runs It gets mounted, but superCoolCatalog does not have anything within it.
I have also tried to mount network drive like this -
volumes:
   z_drive:
     driver_opts:
       type: cifs
       o: user=user,password=12345,uid=1000,gid=1000,dir_mode=0755,file_mode=0755
       device: //192.168.8.7/lalaCatalog

This worked perfectly fine. Except that I could not run the image if the device was offline. Should I make share for the usb drive? Or I can access it directly with the cifs configuration? If so, then how? What I would need to put in device: ?
Thank you!
